# Extract a field by the value of another field

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the JSON file with that structure:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "6a6176c1-b879-8f66-6ccb-2532ec151589",
        "name": "Name",
        "data": {
            "payload": [
                {
                    "initiator": "Manager",
                    "action": "update",
                    "userId": "user",
                    "createdAt": "2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z",
                    "message": "<bulky message 1>"
                },
                {
                    "initiator": "clusterManager",
                    "action": "update",
                    "userId": "user",
                    "createdAt": "2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z",
                    "message": "<bulky message 2>"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I use the `jq` command to parse that JSON.
I could obtain the `createdAt` field to put it into an array.

```bash
CHANGELOG_DATES=($(jq '.[].data.payload[].createdAt' /tmp/changelog.json))

echo ${CHANGELOG_DATES[@]}

"2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z" "2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z"
```

But I can't imagine how to select the `message` field by the `createdAt` field. If I select `"2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z"` I'll get `<bulky message 1>`.

But if try to use map I'll get an error

```bash
jq '.[].data.payload[].map(select(.type == "2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z")' /tmp/changelog.json

.[].data.payload[].map(select(.type == "2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z"): Unknown host
ifconfig: `--help' gives usage information.
```

So I can't understand how to find a field by a value name.

Comment: Do you mean `.[].data.payload[] | select(.createdAt == "…").message`?

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. Given the input of the value of `createdAt` you expect what?

Comment: `Unknown host` ? Are you sure you are exeuting `jq` and not `ssh`. `ifconfig:` What is ifconfig doing here?

Comment: btw, `echo ${array[@]}` has all the same faults as `echo ${array[*]}`. Better to use `declare -p array` to get an unambiguous view. For example, with `echo` you can't tell the difference between `array=( "two words" "three more words" )` and `array=( "two" "words three" "more" "words" )`, and that's before we go into how glob characters behave.

Comment: Similarly, `array=( $(anything) )` is a bad practice -- see [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29). Instead, use `readarray -t array < <(anything)` with modern bash, or `array=( ); while IFS= read -r line; do array+=( "$line" ); done < <(anything)` for compatibility with ancient bash versions like the one shipped by Apple.

Comment: To get beyond kibitzing and focus on the real problem, though, we'd need a [mre] that let us actually reproduce your problem. When "your problem" is an error relating to ifconfig, but the code never calls ifconfig and the data doesn't contain that string, you aren't giving us enough to see the issue ourselves and test proposed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe from the `select` to code that does what you want with the output that passes it.

```
jq --arg time '2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z' '
  .[].data.payload[] | select(.createdAt == $time) | .message
'
```

Loading your messages into a shell array *safely*, in a way that allows for messages that contain spaces, newlines, and other unexpected content (other than NUL literals) is maybe more involved. Using jq 1.7 or later:

```
messages=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' message; do
  messages+=( "$message" )
done < <(jq --raw-output0 --arg time '2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z' '
  .[].data.payload[]
  | select(.createdAt == $time)
  | .message
')
```

...or, compatible with older versions of jq having `-j` but not `--raw-output0`:

```
messages=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' message; do
  messages+=( "$message" )
done < <(jq -j --arg time '2023-11-29T08:46:30.202778Z' '
  .[].data.payload[]
  | select(.createdAt == $time)
  | .message
  | sub("\u0000"; "")
  | (., "\u0000")
')
```